# Why is `export` not working properly in this module?

Tags: module, erlang

What I understand is that `-export()` make it possible to expose some, but not all, functions in a module definition. Inside the module definition, all functions are available, however.

I have a module that looks like this

```
-module(supervisor_test).
-export([start_listening/0, stop_listening/0, send_to_listener/1]).

listener() ->
  receive
    {Pid, Ref, x} ->
      Pid ! {Ref, o};
    {Pid, Ref, o} ->
      Pid ! {Ref, x}
  end.

supervisor() ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, listener, []),
  register(reg_listener, Pid),
  receive
    {'EXIT', Pid, normal} ->    % received when listener() finishes executing
      ok;
    {'EXIT', Pid, shutdown} ->  % received when stop_listening() is called
      ok;
    {'EXIT', Pid, _} ->
      supervisor()
  end.

start_listening() ->
  spawn(?MODULE, supervisor, []).

stop_listening() ->
  Pid = whereis(reg_listener),
  exit(Pid, shutdown).

send_to_listener(Value) ->
  Ref = make_ref(),
  reg_listener ! {self(), Ref,  Value},
  receive
    {Ref, Reply} -> Reply
  after 5000 ->
    timeout
  end.
```

Whenever I compile and call `supvervisor_test:start_listening()`, I get the following error

```
=ERROR REPORT==== ... ===
Error in process ... with exit value:
{undef,[{supervisor_test,supervisor,[],[]}]}
```

It goes away if I `export_all` and expose everything.

I tried compiling

```
  -module(test).
  -export([f1/0]).

  f1() ->
    f2().

  f2() ->
    io:format("I am here!~n").
```

and calling `test:f1()` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `start_listener()` you're calling the MFA version of `spawn()`. This will use `apply()` and the apply docs state: "The applied function must be exported from Module."